# Java error: constructor in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I just added the constructor *Building* and I thought everything would work fine, but I'm getting an error on line 43. When I create the object, `Building b = new Building();`, it says I need to have a `double` and `int` in the argument, so I did as it said, but I just keep getting more errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
// This program lets the user design the area and stories of a building multiple times
// Author: Noah Davidson
// Date: February 20, 2014

import java.util.*;

public class Building // Class begins
{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    double area; // Attributes of a building
    int floors;

    public Building(double squarefootage, int stories)
    {
        area = squarefootage;
        floors = stories;
    }

    void get_squarefootage() // User enters the area of floor
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the square footage of the floor.");
        area = console.nextDouble();
    }

    void get_stories() // The user enters the amount of floors in the building
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of floors in the building.");
        floors = console.nextInt();
    }

    void get_info() // This function prints outs the variables of the building
    {
        System.out.println("The area is: " + area + " feet squared");
        System.out.println("The number of stories in the building: " + floors + " levels");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) // Main starts
    {
        char ans; // Allows for char

        do{ // 'do/while' loop starts so user can reiterate
            // the program as many times as they desire

            Building b = new Building(); // Creates the object b
            b.get_squarefootage(); // Calls the user to enter the area
            b.get_stories(); // Calls the user to enter the floors
            System.out.println("---------------");
            b.get_info(); // Displays the variables
            System.out.println("Would you like to repeat this program? (Y/N)");
            ans = console.next().charAt(0); // The user enters either Y or y until
                                            // they wish to exit the program

        } while(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y'); // Test of do/while loop
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to use new Building() , create an empty constructor in class.

Comment: im supposed to have a constructor building with those two attributes. If i did that, wouldnt it then have none?

Comment: if you create a constructor for your class(a constructor with arguments), java willn't provide the default no-argument constructor for your class, so make sure so include it yourself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is this line here: `Building b = new Building(); // Creates the object b`

Your constructor is set up to take two arguments, a double and an int, but you pass neither.

Try something like this to remove the error:

```
double area = 0.0;
int floors = 0;
Building b = new Building(area, floors);
```

Perhaps a better idea would be to just have a constructor that took no parameters:

```
public Building() {
    this.area = 0.0;
    this.floors = 0;
}
```

After I apply these changes, the code compiles and runs... (see the picture below)

[image: Confirmation that the program compiles and runs]

Comment: when i try and pass it a double and int i get a .class expected error. Not sure what that means either

Comment: Are you sure? I just ran the program, and it works just as expected for me

Comment: im supposed to allow the user to enter their own data unfortunately

Comment: Works for me, to enter my own data...I will post a picture

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed and tested your code. It now runs. You need to add two arguments to the constructor (double and int).

```
import java.util.*;

public class Building // The class begins
{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    double area; // Attributes of a building
    int floors;

    public Building (double squarefootage, int stories)
    {
        area = squarefootage;
        floors = stories;
    }

    void get_squarefootage() // The user enters the area of floor
    {
        System.out.println ("Please enter the square footage of the floor.");
        area = console.nextDouble();
    }

    void get_stories() // The user enters the amount of floors in the building
    {
        System.out.println ("Please enter the number of floors in the building.");
        floors = console.nextInt();
    }

    void get_info() // This function prints outs the vaibles of the building
    {
        System.out.println ("The area is: " + area + " feet squared");
        System.out.println ("The number of stroies in the building: " + floors + " levels");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) // Main starts
    {
        char ans; // Allows for char

        do{ // 'do/while' loop starts so user can reiterate
            // the program as many times as they desire

            double a = 1;
            int c = 2;
            Building b = new Building(a, c); // Creates the object b
            b.get_squarefootage(); // Calls the user to enter the area
            b.get_stories(); // Calls the user to enter the floors
            System.out.println("---------------");
            b.get_info(); // Displays the variables
            System.out.println("Would you like to repeat this program? (Y/N)");
            ans = console.next().charAt(0); // The user enters either Y or y until
                                            // they wish to exit the program

        } while(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y'); // Test of do/while loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Building // Class begins
{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    double area; // Attributes of a building
    int floors;

    void get_squarefootage() // User enters the area of floor
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the square footage of the floor.");
        this.area = console.nextDouble();
    }

    void get_stories() // The user enters the amount of floors in the building
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of floors in the building.");
        this.floors = console.nextInt();
    }

    void get_info() // This function prints outs the variables of the building
    {
        System.out.println("The area is: " + area + " feet squared");
        System.out.println("The number of stories in the building: " + floors + " levels");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) // Main starts
    {
        char ans; // Allows for char

        do{ // 'do/while' loop starts so user can reiterate
            // the program as many times as they desire

            Building b = new Building(); // Creates the object b
            b.get_squarefootage(); // Calls the user to enter the area
            b.get_stories(); // Calls the user to enter the floors
            System.out.println("---------------");
            b.get_info(); // Displays the variables
            System.out.println("Would you like to repeat this program? (Y/N)");
            ans = console.next().charAt(0); // The user enters either Y or y until
                                            // they wish to exit the program

        } while(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y'); // Test of do/while loop
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).