# Constructor Bicycle class cannot be applied to given types;required: int,int found:no argument reason:actual and former argument differ in length

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a Tricycle class extending from Bicycle class but it displays the following error

> Constructor Bicycle class cannot be applied to given types;required: int,int found:no argument reason:actual and former argument differ in length

```
public class Bicycle {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
    // TODO code application logic here
   int speed;
   int tyre;
   int gear;
   short color;
   // constructor for bicycle class
   public Bicycle(int startSpeed,int startGear){

       speed = startSpeed;
       gear = startGear;

   }
   //set Speed method
   public void setSetStartSpeed(int increaseSpeed){

       speed +=increaseSpeed;
   }

   //set Gear method
   public void setGear(int newGearValue){
       gear = newGearValue;
   }
}


public class Tricycle extends Bicycle {

}
```

Comment: Read the error, what is it saying? Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339041/java-error-constructor-in-class-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types

Comment: Add a constructor to your trycycle class that calls the super constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Tricycle` doesn't have any constructor defined, it implicitly has a public constructor with no arguments - this is known as a default constructor. Since you don't have any code that specifies how it calls its super-class' constructor, by default it just calls the super's default constructor, which of course doesn't exist, and thus you get the error you mentioned.

One approach is to explicitly define a constructor that passes parameters on to the super's constructor. This seems like a reasonable solution, as a tricycle could (should?) also have an initial speed and gear:

```
public class Tricycle extends Bicycle {
    public Tricycle(int startSpeed, int startGear) {
        super(startSpeed, startGear);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This has helped me fix the error.